# Storm Kafka spout not emitting messages

Tags: apache-storm

In my storm topology(with 2 spouts and 1 bolt) the offset for one of the the kafka-spout consumer is advancing but the msgs are not sent via kafka spout to the bolt. I can see in the storm ui that for that particular spout the msgs emitted and transferred is 0. 
So, my question is how come the consumer is advancing, i can see the gradual increase in the offset of the consumer from the zookeeper client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later figured out that the reason for the above behaviour was because the serializer registered was filtering out all of the messages from the kafka queue thereby no message was emitted from the spout to the bolt. This also explains why the offsets of the kafka topic consumer group was gradually increasing.